# How many times can one enter Thailand with a tourist visa in these circumstances?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, thailand, visa-free-entry, repeat-visits

I am a bit confused because I read pretty different informations online.
Let's assume this scenario:

- UK passport holder. Older than 18 years old but younger than 50. Otherwise no criminal records or exceptional thing.
- Never visited Thailand before.
- Flies to Thailand (no prior visa).
- Gets stamped for 30 days.
- Before 30 days, renews other 30 days.
- Before 30 days, renews again (approaching 90 days now)
- Before 90 days, flies out (no overstay)
- Flies back to Thailand within one week, and repeats the same operation.

By searching for regulations online, I do not see any regulation on Thai tourist visa policy that explicitly avoids this.
However, I see a lot of people online claiming in practice this cannot be done.

Are there any numbers about how often this can be accomplished?
Is this in any regulation or is just randomly done by the on-duty immigration officer?

Comment: "...Objection your honor: ` . ` Asked and answered..."

Comment: Only partially. Because the answer to that post is a lot of interested information but no answer to this question

Comment: The joke was based on the same user asking and answering his own question.   But now I see that there are two separate users with the username `Traveller`